# Can tell ruby me if a given class wass defined in a given module

Tags: ruby, reflection, class, module

```
Module M
    Class C
    end
end
```

What I need is something like:

```
M.was_defined_here?(M::C)
M.classes.include?(M::C)
```

Does this exists somehow?

I know I could parse M::C.name. But someebody could have the idea to change Module#name, to make it more astetic or something. I want a clean solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
M.constants.map {|c| M.const_get(c)}.include?(M::C)
```

Or, from johannes' comment, using find (will perform better if the class does exist in M and doesn't happen to be the last constant in M - though it should rarely make a measurable difference):

```
M.constants.find {|c| M.const_get(c) == M::C }
```

Edit: Since you actually just want a boolean result, this `any?` makes more send than `find`:

```
M.constants.any? {|c| M.const_get(c) == M::C }
```

Comment: I think M.constants.find { |c| M.const_get(c) == M::C } performs better.

Comment: A good start, but it won't work if M::C doesn't exist at all.

Comment: The problem, as I understood it was: Input: a class object and a module object. Output: Whether the class is defined inside the module. So, at least from my understanding of the problem description, the class has to exist.

Comment: sepp2k understood the question the way I meant it.

Comment: If you know that `M::C` exists, then what are you testing? You won't be able to tell the difference between a class `C` that was declared within `M` and one that was declared elsewhere but `M` adds it to its namespace.

Comment: Gaius: My understanding is that `M.was_defined_here?(M::C)` should return true and `M.was_defined_here?(String)` should return false. So `M.was_defined_here?(someobj.class)` should return true if and only if obj is an instance of one of the classes defined in M.

Answer (score 2):

[sepp2k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445943/can-tell-ruby-me-if-a-given-class-wass-defined-in-a-given-module/1446121#1446121) won't work if `M::C` is not defined at all, since Ruby will raise a `NameError` in that block.

Try this:

```
M.constants.include?('C')
```

If you're worried that you have a reference to `M::C` by a different name, like so:

```
module M
  class C
  end
end

MY_M_C = M::C
```

then you can test whether `MY_M_C` is the same as `M`'s `C` like so:

```
M.constants.include?('C') ? MY_M_C == M.const_get(:C) : false
```

Comment: why not use `M.const_defined?(:C)` instead?

Comment: That'll work just as well and will perform at least as well as mine. Nice one.