# ruby: How can I get all the Class and/or Module objects that are a child of a Module?

Tags: ruby

Supposing I have the following:

```
module A
  class B
    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

And suppose I have several different files like this, with different values of B, but all in the same module (A).  From a program that `require`'s a file that then `require`'s each of these files, is there a way with introspection/reflection (are these different things?  I'm hazy on the distinction, if so) to determine (and get objects for) each class within the module?

I've tried this, which gets me sort of close:

```
A.constants # => ["B"]
```

But I'd prefer to get back `[A::B]`, rather than a string, so that I can then call something like `singleton_methods` on it, which would be useful to my program, which is attempting to map data into calls into the various subclasses' methods.

Is there some way to do this?  I've been digging for answers, and found a few related things, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436159/how-to-get-all-subclasses) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445943/can-tell-ruby-me-if-a-given-class-wass-defined-in-a-given-module), but nothing that's quite spot on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hah!  Wouldn't you know it?  Just after writing this, I discovered an answer that seems to work for me:

```
A.constants.collect{|k| A.const_get(k)}.select {|k| k.is_a?(Class)} # => [A::B]
```

Sweet, that was easy, once I put the right pieces together.  :)

Comment: yeah, its most often like that if you try to express your problem with words. This action is giving a unique viewpoint to your brain :)

Comment: Just remember, code is read more often than it is written. Your answer may be readable, but it's not *very* readable.

Comment: @GregKrsak: Feel free to propose an alternative, as a separate answer.  :)  If it strikes me as more readable than than my own, I promise to upvote it.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

thats my final solution based on lindes answer:

```
    def all_classes_in_module_except_base(module_class)
      Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/domains/#{module_class.to_s.underscore}s/*.rb"].each { |file| load file }
      module_class.constants.collect { |k| module_class.const_get(k) }.select { |k|
        k.is_a?(Class) && k.name.demodulize != "Base"
      }
    end
```

Comment: Isn't this then Rails-specific, though? And going unnecessarily to the file system for part of the answer? Not sure what exactly you were trying to solve; was it not solved by my original answer? What was missing?

Comment: you are right, we ended up using: extend ActiveSupport::DescendantsTracker in out Base class.